# Using templating/overlay libraries in operators

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kustomize, kubernetes-operator

While building operators using **OperatorSDK: Go** framework, we end up creating Kubernetes resources such `Deployments`, `Services` etc programmatically by leveraging structs from k8s modules/packages. Compared to creating these manifests in yaml/json formats, this is quite cumbersome and requires quite a bit of coding. And any changes to the manifest would require code changes and the new version of the operator needs to be rolled out.

I am wondering whether existing templating/overlay tools such as Helm or Kustomize can be used for building these k8s resources within the operator code. This would also enable you to externalise the manifest/template files from the operator code. I couldn't find any good examples of how these tools can be used as modules/libraries within a Go program. Please provide any pointers, suggestions or alternate approaches.

Related question: [Kubernetes operator create Deployment using yaml template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68255140/kubernetes-operator-create-deployment-using-yaml-template)

This talks about how you can read a yaml file and unmarshal it into a Deployment object. Here, I would still need to code templating/overlay logic within the operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the helm engine programmatically, by calling [engine.Render](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/a4d6c736bcf3e8eacb4b89be216cd3f02f252de8/pkg/engine/engine.go#L73).

```golang
func Render(chrt *chart.Chart, values chartutil.Values) (map[string]string, error)
```